# Dynamically construct tuple from vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've got an interesting problem where I need to dynamically create a tuple  from a vector where the number of type parameters of tuple equals the length of the vector.

```
vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3};
tuple<int, int, int> t1 = create_tuple(v1);
vector<int> v2 = {1,2};
tuple<int, int> t2 = create_tuple(v2);
vector<int> v3 = {1};
tuple<int> t3 = create_tuple(v3);
```

I'm guessing this can only be done, if possible, at compile time?

Comment: the size of tuple must be known at compile time. The size of vector can be known only at runtime, so no it is not possible.

Comment: _"I need to"_ No you don't.

Comment: @bolov: Please please please please stop writing answers as _comments_.

Comment: With continuation passing style and an upper limit to tuple size, this is doable.  Unwise, but doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it can only be done at compile-time: the "members" of a tuple are baked into its type.